# Finding the lowest and highest of four numbers without an array

Tags: javascript

I'm supposed to find the highest and lowest of four numbers without the use of an array. How can I go about doing this?

My apologies, I forgot to link my code.

```
    var num1, num2, num3, num4;

num1 = prompt("Enter the first number.");
num2 = prompt("Enter the second number.");
num3 = prompt("Enter the third number.");
num4 = prompt("Enter the fourth number.");

if (num1 < num2)
{
    if (num1 < num3)
    {
        if (num1 < num4)
            {
                var lowest = num1;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do it if I handed you four pieces of paper with numbers written on them, and I took away your computer?

Comment: Do you show us some code that you tried, Initial values and the out put that you are expecting.

Comment: You can try writing code to solve this problem.

Comment: That was my bad, I completely forgot to link the code! Updating in a few.

Comment: What's the problem you have with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Compare nr 1 with nr 2. Save the biggest as X. Compare X with nr 3. Save the highest again as X. Compare with nr 4. Save highest as X, which now is the highest number. Now you can probably figure out how to get the lowest...

Answer (score 0):

```
var num1, num2, num3, num4;

num1 = prompt("Enter the first number.");
num2 = prompt("Enter the second number.");
num3 = prompt("Enter the third number.");
num4 = prompt("Enter the fourth number.");

var highest=num1;

if (highest < num2)
{
    highest = num2;
}

if (highest < num3)
{
    highest = num3;
}

if (highest < num4)
{
    highest = num4;
}

alert(highest);

var lowest=num1;

if (lowest > num2)
{
   lowest = num2;
}

if (lowest > num3)
{
    lowest = num3;
}

if (lowest > num4)
{
    lowest = num4;
}

alert(lowest);
```